# How to optimize this rogue´s knockout combo?

Tags: dnd-4e, optimization, powers

I use a combo with my Rogue to kill the target within one turn. It goes like this:

My rogue has Slaying in Action feat (MP II 131) which lets me use my sneak attack again, when I use a action point. So every time I hit an enemy with the Daily Power Knockout (PH 121) and knock it unconscious, I spend an action point to do a Coup de Grace. I use a Vicious Weapon that gives a bonus to critical, so when I hit the Coup de Grace the enemy takes damage from my Vicius Weapon, my Sneak Attack and the power I choose to use with the Coup de Grace.

I normally use with the Coup de Grace the power that has the most Weapons. For me it is Precise Incision which deals 3[W] damage. I also have a multi class with ranger, so I apply the Quarry damage to the Coup de Grace as well.

With all that I average 62,5 points of damage in the Coup de Grace alone, which is enough to kill a creature with 125 Hit Points.

I was wondering if there is a way to optimize the damage with the Coup de Grace. I though about, using a power from another class with multiclass.

Which class and power could I use? what´s the best way to deal the most damage during the Coup de Grace?

Is there any other way to improve this combo (items, feats, powers, etc)?

I'm a level 13 rogue, but any ideas would be welcome, regardless of the level.

Comment: Are you specifically looking to maximize damage dealt while Coup de Grace'ing the target? If so you're basically looking to optimize Critical hit damage and effects triggering off of critical hits.

Comment: I think the best way to optimize that combo is increasing the damage in the Coup de Grace, but I could be wrong. But even if that´s the case, the question remains, what´s the best way to deal the most damage during the Coup de Grace?

Comment: Could someone with DDI access replace the images with DDI links, so we're not copying WotC's stuff?

Comment: I didn´t know I could not do that... I´m sorry..

Comment: Which target, which level? How wedded to this daily are you?

Comment: Any target susceptible to the Knockout Rogue´s power. I don´t see how the level applies.. any level I guess... As for the power, if you know any other way to kill an enemy within a single turn, with a rogue, besides this combo, be my guess...

Comment: The level applies because it you're level 6, you're probably not as interested in a level 18 5[W] power as you would be in a level 7 4[W] power - though the latter would be good info for the long term.

Comment: Oh...  Of course, sorry for that. I'm a level 13 rogue, but any combo suggestions would be nice, regardless of the level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At level 13, the record damage at-will is 109 damage per round across multiple targets.

If you're interested in knocking out people and killing them in their "sleep" you should be an executioner (assassin). Their Assassin's strike power is designed to kill people in their sleep and would do a respectable bonus 40 damage on top of your normal attack, not counting the use of daily poisons or whatnot.

Looking at the [Executioner's handbook](http://community.wizards.com/content/forum-topic/2907671), the guild executioner bumps it up a few d10 (depending on level) and synergises well with a Rogue multiclass focused on the knockout daily for a nova.

Look at the [Anything Goes](http://community.wizards.com/comment/35111891#comment-35111891) builds for full details of the nova at your level.

Notably, take the following feats:

Feats

- L1: Sneak of Shadows
- L2: Light Blade Expertise
- L4: Weapon Focus (light blade)
- L6: Cunning Stalker
- L8: Surprising Charge
- L10: Shadow Master
- L10: Adept Power (retrained Weapon Focus (light blade))
- L11: Lasting Frost
- L11: Wintertouched (retrained Cunning Stalker)
- L12: Deft Blade

With standard frostcheese items.